# JQuery Hide all next divs

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have five divs with different ID's but same class name. Each div have two radio buttons: `Yes and No`. If user selects `No` in a div the next div will be shown, and if he selects `Yes`, a message should be shown with all divs hide (except previous ones).

There is a scenario if user selects No in first 4 divs, then he again selects Yes in the second  div, the third and fourth should get hide, but first should remain visible.
How can I hide all next divs?

This is my HTML structure:

```
 <div id="div1" class="mydiv">
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio1yes" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q1" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio1no" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q1" runat="server" Text="No" />
</div>
<div id="div2" class="mydiv" class="ques">
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio2yes" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q2" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio2no" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q2" runat="server" Text="No" />
</div>
<div id="div3" class="mydiv">
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio3yes" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q3" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio3no" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q3" runat="server" Text="No" />
</div>
<div id="div4" class="mydiv">
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio4yes" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q4" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio4no" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q4" runat="server" Text="No" />
</div>

<div id="div5" class="mydiv" style="display: none">
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio5yes" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q5" runat="server" Text="Yes" />
<asp:RadioButton ID="radio5no" CssClass="quest" GroupName="Q5" runat="server" Text="No" />
</div>
```

and my JQuery

```
$('.quest :radio').each(function (i, obj) {
 $(obj).click(function () {

    var Id = $(obj).val();
    switch (Id) {
    case "radio1yes":
        alert("Message");
        break;
    case "radio1no":
        $("#div2").hide();
        break;
    case "radio2yes":
        alert("Message");
        break;
    case "radio2no":
        $("#div3").hide();
        break;
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: use .nextAll() method

Comment: Yes it works, but its hiding all Divs(Including footer), I just want to hide these specific divs

Comment: as per your comment I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nextAll method](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) like below:

```
$("#div2").nextAll('[id^=div]').hide();
```